# Why is my button only click-able in selected areas?

Tags: swiftui

I have a button but it seems to be clickable only in select areas. I have tried playing around with frames etc but to no avail.

```
            Button(action: {
                print("HELLO")
            }){
                Text("HELLO")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Rectangle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1.0))
            }
```

Comment: Without changing anything of your code the button works in the whole red rectangle as expected (clickable) for me. If this is not the case for you, then the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You don't say if your testing with a real device or the simulator, if it is a real device there is a possibility you have an issue with the hardware, did you test it on multiple platforms. Are you confident that everything is up-to-date? Are you running the latest version of Xcode? Under the latest version of OSX? Did you install Xcode yourself, did you get it from Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a .contentShape modifier:

```
Button(action:, label:)
  .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
```